# How to pass a Null date variable to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, null, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for the best practice, real solution, to send a `Null` to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table, when a date is unknown.

I read some inputs from a formview, and a date field maybe unknown. The database allows Null values in the field but the VB to store the Null prior to a parameterized query update is not working/eludes me.

```vb
    Dim tb2 As TextBox = TryCast(FormView1.FindControl("tbPurchDate"), TextBox)
    Dim purDT As Date
    If tb2.Text = "" Then
        IsDBNull(purDT)    ' Tried this along with other possible code
    Else
        purDT = Convert.ToDateTime(tb2.Text)
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean this, I tried it....Dim purDT As Nullable(Of DateTime)

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I think I stated that in the OP as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the date is unknown, send `DbNull.Value` as the parameter's value:

```
If dateIsUnknown Then
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter _
                       With {.ParameterName = "@purDT", _
                             .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date, _
                             .Value = DBNull.Value})
Else
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter _
                       With {.ParameterName = "@purDT", _
                             .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date, _
                             .Value = theDateVariable})
End If
```

Or if you prefer,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {
                   .ParameterName = "@purDT",
                   .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
                   .Value = If(dateIsUnknown, DBNull.Value, DirectCast(theDateVariable, Object))}
                  )
```

It is necessary to cast the variable to be of type Object so that the If operator has a common type to return. The Value parameter expects an Object.

Comment: Mortan, Works, clean, formatting is outside my convention but I can live with that, and it works great. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @marc11h You're welcome :) I wouldn't normally format it like that either, but it did fit into the available width.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Nullable(Of Date)` to allow your `purDT` variable to also be `Nothing`:

```vb
Dim purDT As Nullable(Of Date) = Nothing

If tb2.Text <> "" Then
    purDT = Convert.ToDateTime(tb2.Text)
End If
```

However, the magic happens when you define the SQL parameter that will hold this value. The parameter should either be `DBNull.Value` or a valid (non-null) `Date`:

```vb
' initialize connection, command...

Dim param = New SqlParameter()
param.ParameterName = "NullableDate"
param.Value = IIf(purDT Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, purDT)

cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data method you are using to send the data to the server.

purDate is a variable of DateTime type and it cannot be set to null.

I suggest you use IsDate instead of testing length.

```
    Dim purDT As Date
    If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
        purDT = Nothing
    Else
        purDT = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Dim purDT As Nullable(Of Date)

If tb2.Text = "" Then
    purDT = DBNull.Value
Else
    purDT = Convert.ToDateTime(tb2.Text)
End If
```